# How to write clean code in Android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, navigation-drawer

I am using Navigation drawer activity in which I am creating a List of Items(on Main Page). Now the code for Navigation drawer is pretty big. How do I add the code for creating a list in a separate class and add it to the onCreate() method of the drawer activity. I am asking this only for the sake of writing clean and presentable code.

Comment: If you are using android studio, create a project with navigation drawer. The code will be automatically added. You can do your homework from there.

Comment: @UmarZaii Ya the code is automatically inserted.. after that, I need to create a list using recycler view. Should I insert the code in the onCreate() method of the inserted code? Tell me some better approach

Answer (score 2):

I will give you just the idea and  code accordingly..
the better approach may be : You should create separate dedicated  methods for each important works.

like :

```
      @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initUi();
    setupUi();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
    setUpRecyclerView();

  }

  void initUi(){
  //initialize all views in this method like recyclerview , toolbar etc
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

  }

  void setUpUi(){
   //set up all ui elements , set event handlers click listeners etc 
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
  }
```

And make a separate class MyAdapter and do all adapter stuffs like binding views and creating viewholders in it . And in MainActivity simply make an object of MyAdapter and pass your POJO objects list to it .

Like :

```
MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(List<Student> studentsList);
recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a general idea, some of the practises that you can follow are

- Use proper names for variables
- Use m as prefix for field variables
- It is a common practise to fill a lot of code in methods such as `onCreate()` Use methods to reduce the size of such methods as Elyssian Apps has mentioned.
- Use Utility classes and implement your own Utility classes for commonly used functions such as Network testing